# Solution verification of $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n+1}$ with $x\in\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n+1}$$ $x\in\mathbb{R}$
The sign of the $n-$ term depends on $x$, at least if $n$ is odd.
So I want to take the absolute value and study the absolute sonvergence.
For the reason why $n+1\geq1$, I'll write:

$$|\frac{x^n}{n+1}|\leq |x|^n$$
So $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |x|^n$ si convergent iff $|x|<1$.
For $|x|=1$, I have $x=\pm 1$ and so I say:

1. for $x=1$ then $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n+1}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1^n}{n+1}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n+1}$ si divergent.
2. for $x=-1$ then $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n+1}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}$ that  converges from leibniz criterion.

Now it remains the case $|x|>1$.
For $x>1$ I have $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x^n}{n+1}=\infty$ so the series diverges.

For $x<-1$ this limit does not exist and so the series is irregular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need to see what happens to $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{x^{n}}{n+1}$ for $x<-1$.

You may argue with subsequence:

For $n=2k$, we have $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{x^{2k}}{2k+1}=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{(|x|^{2})^{k}}{2k+1}=\infty$.

So the limit does not go to zero, the series does not converge.

Comment: Ok thannsk! For all the other cases my attempt is correct?

Comment: It goes through.

Comment: Sorry I am not english mother tongue...what's mean what you say? my work is correct or not?

Comment: In particular I am not sure about $|\frac{x^n}{n+1}|\leq |x|^n$

Comment: Yes, yes, it is correct.

Comment: $|x^{n}/(n+1)|=(1/(n+1))|x^{n}|\leq|x^{n}|=|x|^{n}$.

Comment: Ok thanks! The fact that in case $x<-1$ the limit does not exist since the right and left limit are different means that the series is irregular?

Comment: The limit $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}$ has only one direction, there is no left or right direction for this. The fact that it is not convergent is due to its non-convergent subsequence (the even terms $n=2k$). Yes, the series does not converge (irregular in your sense).

Comment: For me the character of a series could be: convergent, divergent or irregular...now it is clear what I mean by irregular?

Comment: That is really weird. Then what is the difference between divergence and irregular?

Comment: irregular= the limit of sequence of partial sum does not exists

Comment: Then it is still the same, the series is irregular in your sense because the tail $a_{n}$ does not converge to zero (because of a divergent subsequence).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** If the series converges then
$$
\lim_n \frac{x^n}{n+1} =0
$$
and hence
$$
\lim_n \left| \frac{x^n}{n+1} \right|=0 \,.
$$

This is an usefull trick to remember when dealing with not necesarily positive series: the divergence test yields that if $\sum_n a_n$ is convergent then $\lim_n |a_n|=0$.

Comment: Ok but my work is right? Abive all what I can say about $x<-1$?

Comment: @cely When $x <-1$ then $|x| >1$ which means you can treat this case exactly the same way you treated the case $x >1$.

Comment: Ah ok so since $\lim_{n\to\infty}|x^n/(n+1)|=\infty$ in case $x<-1$ then the series does not converges...but is divergent or irregular?

Comment: @cely You can show in this case that the partial sums $S_{2n}$ goes to $\infty$ and $S_{2n+1}$ goes to $- \infty$. To see this, observe that $S_{2n+2}-S_{2n} \to \infty$ and $S_{2n+3}-S_{2n+1} \to - \infty$.

Comment: Ah ok so the series is irregular in this case right?

Comment: Moreover for all the other cases my attempt is correct?