# $\left|\frac{x^n}{n+1}\right|\leq |x^n|=|x|^n$

Tags: inequality, solution-verification, natural-numbers

Is it right to say that $\left|\frac{x^n}{n+1}\right|\leq |x^n|=|x|^n$ if $n$ is a natural number $\geq 0$?

This is not an isolated question but it is related to this my [Solution verification of $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n+1}$ with $x\in\mathbb{R}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4127133/900585) previous question. I have tried to ask for this in comments without success so I hope this separated question could help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: yes 1822813819313

Comment: Yes, because$\Bigl|\frac{x^n}{n+1}\Bigr|=\frac{|x|^n}{n+1}$ and $n+1\ge 1$, so $\frac1{n+1}\le\frac 11=1$. Then you can multiply both sides by $|x|^n$, which is non-negative.

Comment: Yes, that's correct .

Comment: Thanks to all of you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is valid: because $f(x) = \frac1{x}$ is strictly decreasing, $n + 1\geq 1$ implies $\frac1{n+1} \leq 1,$ and because $|x| \geq 0$ for any $x$ we can say that $\left|\frac{x^n}{n+1}\right| = \left|\frac{1}{n+1}\right|\cdot|x|^n \leq |x|^n.$